# Importing multiple FedEx WSDL into vb.net

Tags: .net, fedex

I'm incorporating the FedEX Web services into a vb.net application.  I've imported the WSDLs for the various services (rate, shiping/creating label, address validation).  After I've added them as web references I get a SGEN error when building the project:

"The top XML element 'XXX' from namespace '' references distinct types..."

They apparently are reused portions in the seperate WSDL.  So far I've been able to fix the errors by changing:

```
<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.18034"),  _
 System.SerializableAttribute(),  _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute([Namespace]:="http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v2")>  _
Public Enum AddressValidationAccuracyType
```

to include a TypeName such as:

```
<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.18034"),  _
 System.SerializableAttribute(),  _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute([TypeName]:="servAddressValidationAccuracyType", [Namespace]:="http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v2")>  _
Public Enum AddressValidationAccuracyType
```

But this a tedious task and I was hoping there might be a different/proper/better way to eliminate this error without updating all the reference.vb files after adding the wsdl files.  I'm new to using web references and haven't found the FedEx docs to be helpful.